# When is $\sum_{1 \leq n \leq k}n^{-n+k}$ prime?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, summation

Consider the following finite sum $f: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ defined as

$$f(k) = \sum_{1 \leq n \leq k}n^{-n+k}$$
$$ = 2 + 2^{k-2} + 3^{k-3}...+ (k-1)$$
It is easy to see that $f(2) = 2$ and therefore $f(2)$ is prime. By calculating the next few values for small numbers we see that the function $f(k)$ gives non-prime outputs except for

$$f(5) = \sum_{1 \leq n \leq 5}n^{-n+5} = 23$$
$$f(8) = 733$$

My question is, when is $f(k)$ prime?

EDIT:
Due to the contributions of @kodlu , we know that
$$f(72) = 302155729822807067683647339069918655121463860225627810920499638685341$$ is also prime

Comment: There is an explicit formula for this sum in terms of the Bernoulli numbers. You might, or might not, be able to deduce primality (probably easier to see a *lack* of primality) from this

Comment: 2,5,8, and 72 yield primes [checked until 10^3]. which are 2,23,733, and

Comment: Yeah you're right! However the formula works for a positive constant exponent and here we have $n$... If you see a way to make this work please do tell me or show

Comment: 302155729822807067683647339069918655121463860225627810920499638685341 is the prime corresponding to $k=72.$

Comment: @kodlu Woah! Thanks

Comment: sequence is already in OEIS : https://oeis.org/A273976

Comment: @kodlu thank you for your contributions! The question still stands though. When is it prime? I'm hoping to find some formula connecting 2, 5, 8, 72, ...

Comment: Good luck, of course it still stands.

Comment: I wouldn't hope for any useful formula that would give you more primes or any connection between them. To understand this, just make up any sequence that grows quickly and does not have any obvious factors, and you will observe the same behavior. Small numbers are simply much more likely to be primes. Also if there was any useful formula for generating arbitrary large primes we wouldn't have the term  "largest known prime number" ... Though I admit that $f(72)$ is a large example, but those are possible too, just unlikely...

Comment: Just as an example I made up $h(k)=\sum_{i=1}^{k}i^{2i}$, and it seems to be prime for $k=2$ and $k=298$ and then I can't find any more... The second one has 1475 digits ... But the same would happen if I would just take random integers with $k$ digits (or however quick the sequence should grow) ... This is not to discourage you, but it is good to be realistic with expectations :)

Comment: This is not really large ! Many many sequences produce many primes , even quite large ones , and suddenly there are no more primes in a reasonable range. Sil is right, the hope for a useful way to construct REALLY large primes is $0$ (although one might be lucky to hit a formula and a suitable value for $n$ producing by chance a huge prime , but this is then a matter of luck, not of clever construction).

Comment: Incredible how often a strange sequence turns out to be already in OEIS :)